# what BSD license c/c++ library can use to implement http client support http1.1 and ssl

Tags: c++, c, http, ssl, https

I'm looking for a c/C++ library that implements or enables the implementation of a HTTP client. It should support http1.1 and ssl as well.
What would you propose?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: libcurl would do, I guess. Also searching the SO would help.

Answer (score 2):

`libcurl` supports HTTP1.1, TLS, and appears to be under a license similar to BSD:

```
 All rights reserved.
 .
 Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for any purpose
 with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright
 notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
 .
 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT OF THIRD PARTY RIGHTS. IN
 NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
 DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR
 OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE
 OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 .
 Except as contained in this notice, the name of a copyright holder shall not
 be used in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use or other dealings
 in this Software without prior written authorization of the copyright holder.
```

Answer (score 1):

Beast supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1, and it works with Boost.Asio regular sockets or SSL streams. It is part of Boost, with plenty of documentation and builds on gcc, clang, and Visual Studio! https://github.com/boostorg/beast/

Here's a complete example program:
Use HTTP to request the root page from a website and print the response:

```
#include <beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "boost.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "http"}));

    // Send HTTP request using beast
    beast::http::request_v1<beast::http::empty_body> req;
    req.method = "GET";
    req.url = "/";
    req.version = 11;
    req.headers.replace("Host", host + ":" + std::to_string(sock.remote_endpoint().port()));
    req.headers.replace("User-Agent", "Beast");
    beast::http::prepare(req);
    beast::http::write(sock, req);

    // Receive and print HTTP response using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    beast::http::response_v1<beast::http::streambuf_body> resp;
    beast::http::read(sock, sb, resp);
    std::cout << resp;
}
```